# Getting twitter Profile data in C#

Tags: c#, json, c#-4.0, twitter

I am creating an app in C# where the user enters their name and respective profile data is received from Twitter. I am not using an API for now. If I use:

https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=kool_aid_wino

the response is a JSON message like this.

```
{"id":184937673,"id_str":"184937673","name":"Brautigan's Ghost","screen_name":"Kool_Aid_Wino","location":"","description":"Author Richard Brautigan floating through time. Fan Account.","url":null,"protected":false,"followers_count":1803,"friends_count":623,"listed_count":97,"created_at":"Mon Aug 30 21:21:12 +0000 2010","favourites_count":0,"utc_offset":-18000,"time_zone":"Quito","geo_enabled":false,"verified":false,"statuses_count":653,"lang":"en","status":{"created_at":"Fri Jun 15 00:47:15 +0000 2012","id":213432448762134528,"id_str":"213432448762134528","text":"I sat beside my little brother on the front porch, and I told him a story about a flower that fell in love with a star.","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitterrific.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitterrific\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweet_count":11,"favorited":false,"retweeted":false},"contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"C0DEED","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1114076851\/Brautigan_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1114076851\/Brautigan_normal.jpg","profile_link_color":"0084B4","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"show_all_inline_media":false,"default_profile":true,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null}
```

There are few queries I have in my mind:

- Do I need a JSON parser in C# to go through the JSON message?
- This JSON message doesn't contain information about promoted tweets,How can I get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the documentation for [Twitter's REST API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api).
You can use them as below:

```
using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
    string searchText = "kool_aid_wino";
    string json = wc.DownloadString("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?rpp=100&q="+searchText);
    dynamic dynJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
    foreach (var result in dynJson.results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} --> {1} : {2}\n", result.from_user, result.to_user, result.text);
    }
}
```

PS: You will need [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) (my favorite json parser) to run above code

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need a JSON parser in C# to go through the JSON message?

Well, technically the answer is yes but I'm assuming you're asking if you need a 3rd party one. C# has the JavaScriptSerializer class which can take this JSON and convert it to an object as long as you define the class with the appropriate properties first.

Comment: what about the other things? why I am not getting Tweets and promoted tweets with it?